Can't change the background color of window in `customtkinter`
I am trying to change the background color of a CTk window using customtkinter, but nothing seems to work. Regardless of what color I try to set, the window always shows the system default dark background color. Here’s what I have tried so far:
import customtkinter as ctk

# Attempt to set background color directly in constructor
window = ctk.CTk(bg_color='red')

window.mainloop()

I also tried using the configure method:
import customtkinter as ctk

window = ctk.CTk()

# Attempt to configure background color after initialization
window.configure(bg_color='red')

window.mainloop()

But neither of these methods change the background color of the window. It remains the default dark color provided by customtkinter.

customtkinter use fg_color to set the background color:
window.configure(fg_color='red')

See official document.

You can test it :
window.configure(background='red')


Doesn't  work even after doing the following

You can set ctk.CTkFrame to have a fg_color parameter
import customtkinter as ctk

root = ctk.CTk()

frame = ctk.CTkFrame(master=root, corner_radius=0, fg_color="red")
frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

root.mainloop()

